# Avoiding two primary buttons on wizard

Tags: website-design, interactive-ui

I'm designing a a web page which have a wizard.

On this wizard, in one step, the user should upload one or more images, and then continue. This is the mockup:

[image: photos mockup]

On this case, how can I avoid having two primary buttons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the buttons doesn't have the same kind of functionality I would give them different positions and different looks.

Save and continue
 - Control for the wizard itself
 - Not main task of this step
 - Needs consistent positioning and behavior

Add photo
 - Main task for this step and should have focus
 - Button is related to the photos, rather than to the wizard itself

I would maybe approach this with something like this

[image]